Constraints (Transformation) are not working as expected
Help me understand the constraints.
My wheel is attached to the empty box so that it rotates along the forward x-axis as the empty box moves LOCALLY forward (direction - minus Y ).

And everything works fine until I try to move the wheel in different directions, then it can spin in the opposite direction of logic.

I suspect that the problem is with this constraints, but I don't know what I did wrong.

Help figure out how to properly configure or reorganize constraints.
UPD:
In the constraints, I left enabled the constraint that does not work properly (Transformation.003) (Because if you turn it off, it does not work at all). But there are two more constraints for the minimally understandable operation of the device. Even if those two constraints are turned off, the system still works incorrectly.
 (Blender v 4.1.0)

is it possible you "forgot" that you got other transformations (006) (at the end) with world space? [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/3TPQrNlD.png

@Chris They are all turned off, leaving only those that are necessary for minimal work. Even if you remove them all completely, the wheel behaves incorrectly.

I guess you make it more complicated with all these constraints, can't you just parent the wheel to the empty instead of the other Transformation and Copy Location constraints?

@moonboots The idea was that the wheels independently rotate in the right direction regardless of which way you turn and independently of each other. And the "Local Space" item should provide this, but for some reason it does not work correctly.

What does it give if you keep only one Transformation constraint for the wheel, remove the others, parent to the empty called Box_empty_leg_R?
